# IOS - Working with autolayout and drawRect

Tags: ios, core-graphics, autolayout, uiviewanimation, drawrect

I'm working with autolayout and I have a RoundView class (subview of UIButton) which drawRect method is:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGFloat lineWidth = 0.0;
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, _currentBackgroundColor.CGColor);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, self.bounds);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

}
```

Then I add it to self (a UIView), set its width and height using autolayout. Everything looks great.
But when I change its size constraints (to have a bigger view), and call

```
[self layoutIfNeeded];
```

in an animation block, the circle pixels look bigger and ugly.

Do I do this the correct way ?

[image: correct]
[image: incorrect]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just got it from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156548/custom-uiviews-drawrect-never-called-if-initial-frame-is-set-to-cgrectzero) !

The problem was that the os wasn't calling drawRect at each animation step.
To force it, in RoundView's init:

```
self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the content scale into account for the retina displays `[UIDevice mainScreen].scale`. See answers to this (question)[[CGContext and retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545547/cgcontext-and-retina-display])

Comment: Thx but it's not about the retina display. If I set the bigger size first, it will look clean